# typescript cannot find graphql module

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript project and when I compile it, I get the below errors:

```
$ tsc
node_modules/@types/graphql-upload/index.d.ts:10:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graphql'.

10 import { GraphQLScalarType } from "graphql";
                                     ~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index.d.ts:18:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'form-data'.

18 import FormData = require('form-data');
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Comment: Did you actually install those dependencies?

Comment: I started today with Typescript and I don't know which dependencies I have to install

Comment: Same as any Javascript project. Javascript (and by extension Typescript) lacks a standard library, so *anything* you import/require will need to be your code or a dependency you install via npm/yarn. It looks like you maybe installed the type annotations without installing the actual libraries?